# Images in UIImageView not showing in UITableView when circular mask is applied to the ImageView unless scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, calayer

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have a UITableView within a main view contoller.  Within the prototype cell, I have a UIImageview.  In the code below everything works until I add the 5 lines to apply a circular mask and border.  Once I do that, the images will not load unless I scroll the cells. The mask and border do get applied perfectly however.  Will be great when it works... but until then.

Certainly this has been seen before.  I'm a swift/objective-C newbie.

Working in swift for this one.

Code below;

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mixerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MixerTableViewCell

    // set label background color to clear
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    // set highlight selection to none
    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    // set image for cell
    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    // put circular mask and border. This is the problem code that causes initial load of the tableview images to show up blank.
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2;
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true;

    let color1 = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor as CGColorRef
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    imageView.layer.borderColor = color1

    // assign image
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: mixerSounds[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

[initial view load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg7wx.png)

[after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kTIQ.png)

Comment: change the imageview name to image_view may be its help

Comment: I am trying to load on an actual device.  Will be upset if this is simulator specific issue.  Been scratching my head on this for 24 hours now.

Comment: Loaded on a 6 plus and the 6 plus behavior is the same as the simulator.

Comment: Any solution for this? I didn't see any proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

your code is perfectly working for me. Here i am using Xcode-7. i think you are using Xcode-6.3 or less version. just upgrade it to Xcode- 7. and if you are using the same then just check your heightforRowAtIndexpath or other delegates there should be some issue.
thanks

Comment: Confirmed using xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005).    BTW, it looks like it works for me with 3 or less rows, but as soon I have moe rows... blank images.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the below lines,

```
// replace this
let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

// to

let imageView = cell.yourImageViewName 
/* yourImageViewName is the outlet 
reference name you have given in the 
MixerTableViewCell custom class.
*/
```

Edit 2: Just for debugging purposes,
hardcode the image name and check if the image appears on the all the cells.

```
   imageView.image = UIImage(named: "first1.png")
```

Comment: changed my code as you suggested.  Same result.  I prefer your change though since it is more straightforward and readable.  So thanks! let imageView = cell.soundImageIcon  But still have the blank images on initial load... :-(

Comment: So I did that.  It works the same but now with the same image instead of the images names related to indexPath.row.  Meaning, that when I add 3 rows it works fine.  when I had 4, 6, 7 or more... the image still shows up blank... until I scroll the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cellIdentifier = "cell"

    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    cell.image_View.image = UIImage(named: mixerSounds[indexPath.row])
    println("The loaded image: \(image)")
    cell.image_View.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.image_View.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.image_View.layer.cornerRadius = image.frame.height/2
    cell.image_View.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell

}
```

Give imageview outlet to cell and not give imageview name because by default name is imageview so take diffrent name

Comment: sorry, I don't understand how this is different.  I am still stumped on this one.    As soon as I apply circle mask and border, they don't show up until scrolled.  Without the circle mask they show up fine on initial load of the tableview.  Errr....!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is using `clipToBounds = true` I am facing the same issue while making circular `UIImageView` inside `UITableViewCell`

I didn't find the exact solution but for now I found a way to do this

```
if (indexPath.row == indexPath.length && !isTableReloaded)
{
    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.000000001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.reloadTableView()
        })
}

func reloadTableView()
{
    isTableReloaded = true
    self.tableViewContacts.reloadData()
}
```

Here `isTableReloaded` is a `Bool` type `var` which is initialized to `false` in `viewDidLoad()`
and the `if` condition is to be placed at the last of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but before `return` statement

> This will resolve our problem but do not rely on this as this is not the best approach.

Please post solution for this if any one found the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

First: Images doesn't load until you scroll, because when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` methods called the constraints doesn't set for image until now, so when scrolling the constraints was added and the image appears, so if you set proportional width and height for `imageView` (width==height) in cell then
do that
`let w = tableview.frame.width*(proportional value like 0.2)`
`imageView.layer.cornerRadius = w / 2`
`imageView.clipsToBounds = true;`

Answer (score 0):

```
let width = cell.frame.size.width
cell.img.layer.cornerRadius = width * 0.72 / 2
```

0.72 is the ratio of the cell width to image width, for eg. `cellWidth = 125` and `imageWidth = 90`, so 125/90 would give 0.72. Do similar calculation for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfect and state away solution for circular image in UITableview Cell.
Simply modify your UITableviewCell (custom cell) class with below code.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    imgEvent.layer.frame = (imgEvent.layer.frame).insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    imgEvent.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    imgEvent.layer.cornerRadius = (imgEvent.frame.height)/2
    imgEvent.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imgEvent.clipsToBounds = true
    imgEvent.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    imgEvent.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
  }
```

It will also helps to solve the problem of image circular only after scrolling table..(if any!)[image]